# Excel VBA: how to disable shortcut CTRL + period

Tags: excel, vba

I want to disable the annoying keyboard shortcut [CTRL + period](https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/excel-shortcuts-ctrl-period-to-jump-to-next-corner/).

I already have a PERSONAL.XLSB document where I was able to disable the help key (F1) using `Application.OnKey "{F1}", ""`, as explained in the top comment [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/7i4un8/how_to_disable_f1_help_hotkey_permanently/).

I tried to disable CTRL + Period using `Application.OnKey "^.", ""` and similar (`"^{.}"`, etc), but my attempts were unsuccessful.

Do you know how to disable this specific shortcut?

Thank you

Comment: `Application.OnKey "^.", ""` works for me.

Comment: @Rory it does not work for me. I have an Italian keyboard, I don't know if this could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is  Code CTR +

Application.OnKey "^{+}", "InsertProc"

Comment: this specific code disable the shortcut CTRL +, I want to disable CTRL .

Comment: Disable This Workbook or You have any form